Git feature branch rebasing from local configuration branch
I have a GitHub fork of a repository which I have a local copy of to implement a feature.
The project is a multi-platform Flutter app. It requires some changes to be made to it to allow the project to be built on my machine and then be deployed to my testing device. I don't want to push changes to the fork which are just to do with my local configuration.
My workflow is to create a "local-config" branch that makes the necessary changes to run on my device, then I create another branch that JUST implements the features, lets call it "feature-branch" and then to test it, I rebase "local-config" from "feature-branch".
To undo the rebase I use git rebase --onto master local-config feature-branch. Then I can push to the remote repository without mixing in configuration changes.
This seems to work fine for a while and then inexplicably it will fail to build giving the error message:
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Uncategorized (Xcode): Could not resolve package dependencies:
  downloaded archive of binary target 'GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport' from
  'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/swiftpm/10.24.0/GoogleAppMeasurementIdenti
  tySupport.zip' does not contain a binary artifact.
  downloaded archive of binary target 'grpcpp' from
  'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.62.2/rc0/grpcpp.zip' does not
  contain a binary artifact.
  fatalError




Error launching application on iPhone.

It will still build on the "local-config" branch. Just not on the "feature-branch".

Note you didn't actually ask a question yet. ;) One thing you can try is to look at git reflog. Checkout a previous commit that is similar, see if it works, and then checkout your current commit again and see if it still fails. If it does, then diff the commits and see if something else is different that you didn't know about already. If it works after  doing that, then "inexplicably" is a pretty good description and it just may remain a mystery.

Thanks for this advice. Unfortunately there is no change picked up by git. I think it's some files in .gitignore that are modified by the Xcode workspace or projectspace.

Your approach of having two branches for this and to rebase before deliveries is the absolute correct approach. The only thing to watch out for is that rebasing might remove implicit dependencies that causes commits to fail to build/run tests successfully1, which to me seems to be the case here?
The remedy for this is to test every single commit after the rebase, and the tool to use for this is git test which let you iterate tests over a range of commits.

1
And let me point out that this is not exclusive to rebase, this might also happen with git cherry-pick or even git add -p.

Ok. I think that's right. I manage to get it to build successfully after running pod deintegrate. But this a) takes a really long time and b) changes Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved, which means I can't undo the rebase, and so can't push to the remote repository without corrupting it. Could you outline how git test would be implemented here? I'm not familiar with this tool.

Does a plain master branch compile out of the box without any files being modified by the build step? If not I would attempt to fix that first.

With git test you define whatever command you want to run, it can be a simple make all, npm run lint or a it can be shell script for a group of commands. I am not familiar with pod but if this is something that only needs to be run when a package configuration file is changed (similar to npm install) then I have added support for only running when needed in my fork of git test.
